SearchAnchor suggestionBuilder wont Update after hitting X
When clicking on the X in the search to remove the user's input the suggestion list does not update.
The onPressed is implemented in the viewTrailing. When debugging the suggestionBuilder does not get called after the onPressed. Why?
class _SearchAnchor extends StatefulWidget {
  const _SearchAnchor({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<_SearchAnchor> createState() => _SearchAnchorState();
}

class _SearchAnchorState extends State<_SearchAnchor> {
  List<BaseUser> filteredEmployees = [];
  final searchController = SearchController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final availableEmployees = context
        .select((ShiftFormCubit cubit) => cubit.state.availableEmployees);
    // Initialize the filteredEmployees list with all available employees.
    // This ensures that all employees are shown when the widget is first displayed.
    if (filteredEmployees.isEmpty && availableEmployees.isNotEmpty) {
      filteredEmployees = List.from(availableEmployees);
    }
    return SearchAnchor(
        searchController: searchController,
        viewConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: 200.0,
          maxWidth: 250.0,
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, SearchController searchController) {
          return SizedBox(
            width: 250.0,
            child: SearchBar(
              controller: searchController,
              padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsets>(
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)),
              onTap: () {
                searchController.openView();
              },
              leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          );
        },
        suggestionsBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
          return filteredEmployees.map((employee) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(employee.name),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  controller.closeView(employee.name);
                });
              },
            );
          });
        },
        viewOnChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            filteredEmployees = availableEmployees
                .where((element) =>
                    element.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                .toList();
          });
        },
        viewTrailing: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                searchController.clear();
                filteredEmployees = List.from(availableEmployees);
              });
            },
          )
        ]);
  }
}


Instead of setting the values of "availableEmployees" and "filteredEmployees" in the build method, you should define them in the initState method. This ensures they are only updated once when the stateful widget builds.
Here's a simplified version:
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (filteredEmployees.isEmpty) {
      filteredEmployees = List.from(context
        .select((ShiftFormCubit cubit) => 
        cubit.state.availableEmployees));
    }
  }

In the initState method, set 'filteredEmployees' to a copy of 'availableEmployees' only if 'filteredEmployees' is empty. By doing this in initState, the list is updated only once when the widget is initialized, preventing unintended updates triggered by setState calls in the build method

Hi. You can't use context.select outside the build method of a widget.

No, you are wrong you can get widget context in initState method also so try this first.

Maybe you can show me a code snippet that is working, with a context.select within the initState.

if you can send me your whole code then i can help you otherwise i have to make a new project or file to show you.
